# Numeric value for string values

Tags: r, transformation

How could I change string values to any numeric value, as long as each unique string has a unique numeric return.

for example `INTcntry` gets a value `1` for `2708BG`, `2` for `2703BG`... However I don't want to assign it manually, because I have 9000 somewhat different string values.

```
     idno       INTcntry
4039 3857         2708BG
4040 3858         2708BG
4041 3862         2704BG
4042 3863         2704BG
4043 3864         2704BG
4044 3865         2704BG
4045 3867         2704BG
4046 3868         2704BG
4047 3871         2703BG
4048 3872         2703BG
4199  161         1011CH
4201  163         1011CH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `INTcntry` is a factor,

```
is.factor(dd$INTcntry)
```

in which case, just exploit that fact:

```
R> levels(dd$INTcntry)
[1] "1011CH" "2703BG" "2704BG" "2708BG"
R> labels(dd$INTcntry)
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8"
```

so just convert the labels to numeric values:

```
as.numeric(labels(dd$INTcntry))
```

or

```
as.numeric(dd$INTcntry)
```

If `INTcntry` isn't a factor, then just use:

```
factor(dd$INTcntry)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to convert your variable to a factor and then use `as.numeric` :

```
as.numeric(factor(df$INTcntry))
```

Comment: Of course, the question then is, why you need the numeric and cannot just work with the factor.

Comment: That is true, I want to use this data within another program and just wanted to make sure it can read the values properly. But maybe it can read the string values just as good. Will try.